# how can I use sed to separate the body and the other part of a html document?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am having trouble with the Linux command sed

I have a html document that I want to extract the body text and then copy that into a new file, and I am gonna do it with sed:

```
sed '^<body>(.*)<\body>$/p' source.html > bodyextracted
```

but it didn't seem to work

Comment: The canonical source on using regex to parse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4070984

Comment: If you accept answers to your previous questions (http://stackoverflow.com/users/5919843/amber) or explain why they don't solve your problem you might find more people willing to try to help you with future questions.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/<body>/,/<\/body>/p' source.html > bodyextracted
```

This will output since the first occurence of `<body>` to the next occurence of `</body>`.